# Kubernetes API timeout when deploying ingress-controller

Tags: kubernetes, debian, timeout, traefik-ingress

I am using a Self-Managed Bare-Metal kubernetes cluster with the following three nodes:

```
NAME    STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
ruby0   Ready    master   17h   v1.18.5
ruby1   Ready    <none>   17h   v1.18.5
ruby2   Ready    <none>   17h   v1.18.5
```

They are hosted on three identical debian systems with the following kernel (`uname -a`):

```
Linux ruby0 4.19.0-9-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.118-2+deb10u1 (2020-06-07) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

To setup the nodes, I followed the basic installation guide of [Imixs-Cloud](https://imixs.github.io/imixs-cloud/). As mentioned in the tutorial, I've deployed the pod network [flannel](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml). I finished up the installation with the deployment of a traefik ingress-controller, which is explained [here](https://imixs.github.io/imixs-cloud/doc/INGRESS.html#deployment). I left out the 011-persistencevolume.yaml for simplicity.

After that, i got the following traefik service and pod (aswell as deployment and replicaset):

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)                                     AGE
kube-system   service/traefik      LoadBalancer   10.110.149.28   192.168.10.127   80:31298/TCP,443:32383/TCP,8100:31372/TCP   68m

NAMESPACE     NAME                                READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   pod/traefik-b9b444b89-w9b6h         1/1     Running   0          68m
```

When trying to access the traefik service on one of the given ports, either by a browser or curl, I get a timeout error with no response. The given traefik pod shows me the following errors:

```
Trace[1402685037]: [30.000537725s] [30.000537725s] END
E0707 08:08:49.147428       1 reflector.go:153] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.17.3/tools/cache/reflector.go:105: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get "https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout
I0707 08:08:49.148535       1 trace.go:116] Trace[84373527]: "Reflector ListAndWatch" name:pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.17.3/tools/cache/reflector.go:105 (started: 2020-07-07 08:08:19.148006738 +0000 UTC m=+4340.222316899) (total time: 30.000486829s):
Trace[84373527]: [30.000486829s] [30.000486829s] END
E0707 08:08:49.148560       1 reflector.go:153] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.17.3/tools/cache/reflector.go:105: Failed to list *v1.Secret: Get "https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/secrets?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout
I0707 08:08:49.149667       1 trace.go:116] Trace[1117097236]: "Reflector ListAndWatch" name:pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.17.3/tools/cache/reflector.go:105 (started: 2020-07-07 08:08:19.149071171 +0000 UTC m=+4340.223381353) (total time: 30.000553113s):
Trace[1117097236]: [30.000553113s] [30.000553113s] END
E0707 08:08:49.149693       1 reflector.go:153] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.17.3/tools/cache/reflector.go:105: Failed to list *v1.Endpoints: Get "https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/endpoints?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout
I0707 08:08:49.150743       1 trace.go:116] Trace[1553411795]: "Reflector ListAndWatch" name:pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.17.3/tools/cache/reflector.go:105 (started: 2020-07-07 08:08:19.150285239 +0000 UTC m=+4340.224595418) (total time: 30.000416845s):
Trace[1553411795]: [30.000416845s] [30.000416845s] END
E0707 08:08:49.150770       1 reflector.go:153] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.17.3/tools/cache/reflector.go:105: Failed to list *v1alpha1.TraefikService: Get "https://10.96.0.1:443/apis/traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1/traefikservices?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout
10.244.1.1 - - [07/Jul/2020:08:08:53 +0000] "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 200 2 "-" "-" 873 "ping@internal" "-" 0ms
10.244.1.1 - - [07/Jul/2020:08:08:56 +0000] "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 200 2 "-" "-" 874 "ping@internal" "-" 0ms
10.244.1.1 - - [07/Jul/2020:08:09:03 +0000] "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 200 2 "-" "-" 875 "ping@internal" "-" 0ms
10.244.1.1 - - [07/Jul/2020:08:09:06 +0000] "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 200 2 "-" "-" 876 "ping@internal" "-" 0ms
```

For some reason, traefik cannot access the kubernetes API:

```
NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)             AGE
service/kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP             18h
```

I've seen that behaviour on my cluster before, for example when I've installed MetalLB and it tried to access the configmap over the kubernetes API.

Comment: Hello. I used the guides that you provided and I did not stumble upon issues like yours. Could you tell more about the infrastructure you are trying to deploy it on? Can you connect from another pod to the Kubernetes API (10.96.0.1)?